# PHP find an array item by a nested key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array and I need to find an item based on a key within the `tlp_queue_manager_schedulers` object, I tried doing `array_search` but this returned false, I also tried combining this method with `array_column`:

```
[
   {
      "tlp_queue_manager_schedulers":{
         "id":"1",
         "token":"ABC"
      },
      "0":{
         "num":"1"
      }
   },
   {
      "tlp_queue_manager_schedulers":{
         "id":"3",
         "token":"cron-3"
      },
      "0":{
         "num":"2"
      }
   },
   {
      "tlp_queue_manager_schedulers":{
         "id":"4",
         "token":"CronA75nvAgjsm8b"
      },
      "0":{
         "num":"3"
      }
   },
   {
      "tlp_queue_manager_schedulers":{
         "id":"2",
         "token":"XYZ"
      },
      "0":{
         "num":"4"
      }
   }
]
```

For example, I need to return the array item where the `id` key within `tlp_queue_manager_schedulers` matches **3**, this should then return:

```
{
    "tlp_queue_manager_schedulers":{
         "id":"3",
         "token":"cron-3"
    },
    "0":{
         "num":"2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not comparing `3` with `"3"`?

Comment: By all means add your code attempts too.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava unless OP were calling `array_search` in strict mode, that wouldn't make a difference (loose comparison by default).

Answer (score 2):

Good ol' `foreach` loop.  Nothing beats a `foreach` loop:

```php
$matchingObject = null;

foreach($array as $obj)
{
    if($obj->tlp_queue_manager_schedulers->id == "3")
    {
        $matchingObject = $obj;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually gets the job done. I assume this is supposed to be in a function wrapper?

Comment: Maybe.  I don't know in what context this is needed.

Comment: Seeing as you're using `return` there, I'm assuming _the code you posted should be inside a function._ I can imagine OP copy-pasting that smack middle their script and wondering what's happening.

Comment: Oh geez - you're right.  I should be clearer.  Thanks for catching & clarifying.

Comment: Just assuming worst-case copy-paste scenarios with little contextual or syntax understanding being the norm... Could add a `break` when a match is found, then it'd work the same as the previous "function slug" that returned on match instead of iterating 'til the end.

Comment: Another good catch.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

While the `foreach` loop by @Quasipickle would also be my staple fix, since we have a "brevity challenge" vs. Javascript's `array.find()` method, here's a PHP one-liner with `array_filter`:

```
$matches = array_filter($data, 
    fn($row) => $row['tlp_queue_manager_schedulers']['id'] == '3'
);
```

With the sample data given, this returns:

```
array(1) {
    [1] · array(2) {
        ["tlp_queue_manager_schedulers"] · array(2) {
            ["id"] · string(1) "3"
            ["token"] · string(6) "cron-3"
        }
        [0] · array(1) {
            ["num"] · string(1) "2"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that *this will return an array with all items matching the criteria* (retaining original indexes). If no matches are found, an *empty array* is returned. If you're only interested in the first match, then `$match = current($matches);` (no matches: `false`) or `$match = array_shift($matches);` (no matches: `null`) will give you that.

If you have a large dataset and only care about finding the first match item, then `foreach` with a `break` after match is found (or alternatively `return` if your loop is inside a helper function) will potentially save you lots of redundant cycles, since `array_filter` will check the whole array 'til the end. (The difference will be inconsequential for small datasets).

P.S. In case you're wondering why `array_search` won't work: It only looks through array *values*, you can't specify a *key* to check. Even if you first used `array_column`, your column would still be an associative array. You *could* accomplish this with those functions and some level of trickery, however it'd be a long and convoluted solution... Better keep it simple and clean.